# How can I configure Firefox to prevent JavaScript from going full screen?

Tags: firefox

When I double-click on a word on a web page being served by Emby in Firefox, it toggles full screen mode. Presumably it thinks I'm double-clicking on a video.

I'm of the belief that full screen mode should only be toggled by me clicking on the full screen button in the browser chrome, or me pressing the full screen keyboard shortcut. It should *not* be toggled by some random piece of JavaScript.

I had a look through about:config, but there didn't seem to be anything that would handle this (I had high hopes for `dom.disable_window_move_resize` :)

Is there something I can edit in about:config to disable this behaviour? Even if I get the Emby guys to fix their event detection, other web sites could still do the same thing.

[Update: a response from an Emby developer: "It's just a shortcut that we have throughout the entire app. It's convenient on mobile devices." Note the complete lack of consideration for people who *aren't* using mobile devices…]

I'm running Firefox Developer Edition 58.0b12.

Comment: Not sure what main.cpl is — are you talking about the Windows control panel? I'm on a Mac. In any case, the point is that no other web page does this, and no web page SHOULD be allowed to do this.

Comment: Just to be sure, as for _"no web page SHOULD be allowed to do this"_: it's very much by design that JavaScript, if triggered by user interaction, can indeed initiate full screen mode. (Of course, I can understand you might want to disable that. But, for example, I'd not like to watch movies with just a full screen _web site_; instead I want just _the player_ part to go full screen then.)

Comment: Sure, and that's why there should be user controls to disable this, ideally on a per-site basis. But about:config is not always the easiest place to find stuff like this :)